# Использование большого количества изображений в приложении

Tags: android, изображения, память, сжатие

Пишу приложение, которое нуждается в очень большом количестве изображений (около 15 тыс.). Вследствие этого возникает проблема, т.к. изображения занимают по меркам телефона огромное количество памяти (в формате .jpg - чуть меньше 2гб, в формате .png - больше 8гб). Возникает **вопрос**: каким образом уменьшить объем занимаемой памяти: сжатие, уменьшение разрешения и т.д., либо отказ от идеи использовать такое большое количество изображений и сократить их базу? Какие есть выходы из этой ситуации?

Comment: попробуйте хранить изображения на сервере и загружать их динамически

Comment: А можно несколько слов о бизнесовой части задачи - или как принято говорить какие *use case* предполагаются. Без этого невозможно сформулировать архитектуру решения

Comment: @Barmaley если в общих чертах, то есть некоторые элементы, почти каждому элементу соответствует картинка. картинка элемента отображается в ListView со списком элементов и на странице самого элемента

Comment: Это не бизнес-задача. Какую задачу решаете (с точки зрения, чего должна делать программа) - безо всяких `ListView` и проч. программистской мути

Comment: Смотря что за приложение. Зависит от его смысла. Идентификацию картинок, например, можно делать по очень сильно уменьшенной копии. А как такое приложение будет устанавливаться из плеймаркета, если в нем столько фоток?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете хранить ссылки на изображения на сервере и получать с сервера лишь ссылки.

Для загрузки и отображения в Android изображения по url вы можете использовать [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) и [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/)